# Did Lord Shiva write a stotram of Shri Krishna while coming to meet him at Gokula?

Tags: shiva, krishna, stotra

Is there any Stotram of Shri Krishna which Mahadev wrote and sing for the beauty of Baby Shri Krishna (BalKrishna) while coming to meet him in Gokula.